# Add column in Rails 5.1 migration not rolling back properly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration, rollback, ruby-on-rails-5.1

this is my first question here so please be kind.
I recently ran into this issue. 
A migration for adding a column is not rolling back properly. 
I can always do this with SQL statements, but I really wanted to figure out why this was not working.

My migration code looks like this.

```
class ChangeTypeForColumnStatusForInvoices < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  add_column :invoices, :tutor_pay, :integer
  remove_column :invoices, :status, :integer
  add_column :invoices, :status, :string
end
```

Here is the migration and the rollback when executed.

```
jameshong ~/Projects/tad_is_my_boss/toptutoring $ rails db:migrate
W, [2017-08-01T23:43:38.664232 #5782]  WARN -- : [SKYLIGHT] [1.3.1] Running Skylight in development mode. No data will be reported until you deploy your app.
(To disable this message for all local apps, run `skylight disable_dev_warning`.)
-- add_column(:invoices, :tutor_pay, :integer)
   -> 0.0030s
-- remove_column(:invoices, :status, :integer)
   -> 0.0015s
-- add_column(:invoices, :status, :string)
   -> 0.0011s
== 20170801015229 ChangeTypeForColumnStatusForInvoices: migrating =============
== 20170801015229 ChangeTypeForColumnStatusForInvoices: migrated (0.0000s) ====

jameshong ~/Projects/tad_is_my_boss/toptutoring $ rails db:rollback
W, [2017-08-01T23:44:00.076660 #5821]  WARN -- : [SKYLIGHT] [1.3.1] Running Skylight in development mode. No data will be reported until you deploy your app.
(To disable this message for all local apps, run `skylight disable_dev_warning`.)
-- add_column(:invoices, :tutor_pay, :integer)
-- add_column(:invoices, :tutor_pay, :integer)
rails aborted!
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::DuplicateColumn: ERROR:  column "tutor_pay" of relation "invoices" already exists
: ALTER TABLE "invoices" ADD "tutor_pay" integer
/Users/jameshong/Projects/tad_is_my_boss/toptutoring/db/migrate/20170801015229_change_type_for_column_status_for_invoices.rb:2:in `<class:ChangeTypeForColumnStatusForInvoices>'
/Users/jameshong/Projects/tad_is_my_boss/toptutoring/db/migrate/20170801015229_change_type_for_column_status_for_invoices.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
bin/rails:4:in `require'
bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
PG::DuplicateColumn: ERROR:  column "tutor_pay" of relation "invoices" already exists
/Users/jameshong/Projects/tad_is_my_boss/toptutoring/db/migrate/20170801015229_change_type_for_column_status_for_invoices.rb:2:in `<class:ChangeTypeForColumnStatusForInvoices>'
/Users/jameshong/Projects/tad_is_my_boss/toptutoring/db/migrate/20170801015229_change_type_for_column_status_for_invoices.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
bin/rails:4:in `require'
bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::DuplicateColumn: ERROR:  column "tutor_pay" of relation "invoices" already exists
: ALTER TABLE "invoices" ADD "tutor_pay" integer
/Users/jameshong/Projects/tad_is_my_boss/toptutoring/db/migrate/20170801015229_change_type_for_column_status_for_invoices.rb:2:in `<class:ChangeTypeForColumnStatusForInvoices>'
/Users/jameshong/Projects/tad_is_my_boss/toptutoring/db/migrate/20170801015229_change_type_for_column_status_for_invoices.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
bin/rails:4:in `require'
bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
PG::DuplicateColumn: ERROR:  column "tutor_pay" of relation "invoices" already exists
/Users/jameshong/Projects/tad_is_my_boss/toptutoring/db/migrate/20170801015229_change_type_for_column_status_for_invoices.rb:2:in `<class:ChangeTypeForColumnStatusForInvoices>'
/Users/jameshong/Projects/tad_is_my_boss/toptutoring/db/migrate/20170801015229_change_type_for_column_status_for_invoices.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
bin/rails:4:in `require'
bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:rollback
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

As you can see, The migration properly adds column tutor_pay to relation invoices. However, when I rollback, the SQL that is performed is ADD COLUMN instead of DROP COLUMN. According to the rails guide, add_column is supposed to be a reversable migration. I've tried using change table instead. And I still get the same issue.

Would greatly appreciate it if someone could help me figure this out.

Answer (score 3):

Use the below migration:

```
class ChangeTypeForColumnStatusForInvoices < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    add_column :invoices, :tutor_pay, :integer
      remove_column :invoices, :status, :integer
      add_column :invoices, :status, :string
    end
  end
end
```

Or you can also create `self.up` block for executing migration & `self.down` block for rollback [for more info](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#using-the-up-down-methods)

Comment: Yea I figured it out just now. Thanks for answering so quickly though!

Comment: @james You can upvote & accept this answer if it is useful.

Comment: Just did! Earlier it wouldn't let me because I had also posted the answer. Thanks for taking the time to put an answer here!

Answer (score 0):

I probably needed some sleep.

Didn't realize that I had to wrap all of this in a change method.

```
class ChangeTypeForColumnStatusForInvoices < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change      
    add_column :invoices, :tutor_pay, :integer
    remove_column :invoices, :status, :integer
    add_column :invoices, :status, :string
  end
end
```